# haskell parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) in control statement

Tags: parsing, haskell, indentation

I am trying to get something working, its for a game. I have come across a parse error that I am unable to trace.

```
getLineDir :: (Int, Int) -> Piece -> Board -> [Piece]
getLineDir (x,y) (Piece (x',y') player) board 
            | pieceAt(x'+ x, y'+ y) board == Nothing = []
            | if pieceAt(x'+ x, y'+ y) board == Just (Piece _ player') && isPlayer player (Piece _ player') == True then (Piece (x',y') player):[] else (Piece _ player'): getLineDir (x,y) (Piece (x'+x, y'+y) player) board

flippable :: [Piece] -> [Piece]
```

The error message I am getting is:

> parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

I am getting the parse error at the line starting with "flippable" so I'm guessing its something wrong with the previous line.

Comment: Can you add the error message to your question?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, this has been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `==` with a pattern like `Just (Piece _ player')`. You need proper pattern matching as with `case`.

```
getLineDir :: (Int, Int) -> Piece -> Board -> [Piece]
getLineDir (x,y) (Piece (x',y') player) board =
   case pieceAt (x'+ x, y'+ y) board of
   Nothing -> []
   Just piece@(Piece _ player')
     | isPlayer player piece -> [Piece (x',y') player]
     | otherwise -> piece : getLineDir (x,y) (Piece (x'+x, y'+y) player) board
```

Probably, `Just piece@(Piece _ player')` can simply be replaced with `Just piece`, since you never need `player'` after that.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

```
getLineDir :: (Int, Int) -> Piece -> Board -> [Piece]
getLineDir (x, y) (Piece (x', y') player) board 
            | pieceAt(x'+ x, y'+ y) board == Nothing = []
            | pieceAt(x'+ x, y'+ y) board == Just (Piece _ player') && isPlayer player (Piece _ player') == True = (Piece (x', y') player) : [] 
            | otherwise  = (Piece _ player') : getLineDir (x,y) (Piece (x'+ x, y'+ y) player) board
```